# Provisioning APi redirect_uri

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/devguide

For authentication I use the "installed application method" and I obtained the following json from the developer console.

```
{
    "installed":{
            "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "client_secret":"MYSECRET",
            "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "client_email":"",
            "redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","oob"],
            "client_x509_cert_url":"",
            "client_id":"MY CLIENT ID",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
        } }
```

According to the documentation I have to do something like:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage

def create_account_ticket(service):
    """for the body see
    https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/devguide
    search for  Create an Account Ticket using the Provisioning API
    and take a look at:
    https://developers.google.com/resources/api
    libraries/documentation/analytics/v3/python/latest/analytics_v3.provisioning.html
    """
  body_ = {'redirectUri': 'http://localhost',
          'account': {'name': "My Account Name"},
          'webproperty': {'name': 'What kind of name?',
                          'websiteUrl': 'http://www.mywebsite.de'},
          'profile': {'name': 'My Profile name', 'timezone': "Europe/Berlin"},
          }

  res = service.provisioning().createAccountTicket(body=body_).execute()
  return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    storage = Storage('FileContainingToken.dat')
    credentials = storage.get()
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    service = build('analytics', 'v3', http=http)
    t = create_account_ticket(service)
```

When I set the redirect_uri to localhost the response is:

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/provisioning/createAccountTicket?alt=json returned "Value for field 
redirectUrl = `http://localhost` is not valid.">

When I remove the redirect_uri I get as expected: 
"Field redirect URI is required"

According to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#choosingredirecturi

> **localhost**
>
> This value signals to the Google Authorization Server that the
>   authorization code should be returned as a query string parameter to
>   the web server on the client

So this redirect_uri should be valid.

According to the provision api docs

> **Redirect URI** - This is where the user is redirected to and the OAuth
>   2.0 response is sent. Configure Redirect URIs and obtain the Client ID for your project using the Google Developers Console. The value of
>   this parameter must exactly match one of the values registered in the
>   Google Developers Console (including the http or https schemes, case,
>   and trailing '/').

How can I specify the redirect URI for the provisioning API and why the localhost is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't leave a comment yet, I'll leave it as this answer.

> body_ = {'redirectUri': 'http//localhost',

Just at a glance,

```
http//localhost should be http://localhost
```

Comment: thanks, although this is is typo in the code I pasted to SO.thanks for pointing out

Comment: Hey just curious to see if you're still having trouble with this. **http ://localhost** isn't valid because it isn't complete. It should be **http ://localhost.com**